# What does this sentence from Shakespeare mean?

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, shakespeare

Can someone kindly help me translate the following sentence from Shakespeare's language to Modern English through a context:

> "Prithee, would'st thou stay and sup with me in yonder chamber?"

Comment: "Please, would you stay and have dinner with me in that room over there?"

Comment: or, more formally "dine with me" in place of "have dinner with me"

Comment: Hey, pal!!  Let's chow down in that there room.

Comment: Where does the statement come from?  In what text did you read it?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. You need to show us your research efforts and ask us to interpret the part that bothers you most when you ask a question here. This community is neither translation nor dictionary service.

Comment: The sample text appears in this schoolwork quiz *.doc* file, (circa 2011 according to metadata): [TranslatingShakespeareanEnglish.doc](http://www.dpcdsb.org/NR/rdonlyres/EE81D011-0B88-43FF-AFAA-4904FDEC8D61/87223/TranslatingShakespeareanEnglish.doc)

Comment: "Please, would you stay and have supper with me in that room over there?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, more or less, that the speaker is asking "Please, would you stay and dine with me in that room over there?"

[Prithee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prithee) is an archaic contraction of "Pray thee."

[thou](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thou) refers to one person.  Today we would say "you."

[sup](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sup) is related to "sip" and means to take drink a little at a time.  It also suggests "supper" and here means "to dine" or "to have dinner"

[yonder](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yonder) means "over there"